# Visibility changing of div

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a `div` in my `asp.net` page

```
<div runat="server" id="divFinaltargetGroup" visible="false">
    <br />
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Final Target group:</label>
            <wuc:CustomDropDownList ID="ddlFinalTargetGroup" runat="server" Style="width: auto;"></wuc:CustomDropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the `<div id="divFinaltargetGroup">` visible through `jquery` using the `.show()` method but its not working.

Does anyone have an idea...

Comment: You need to provide us with more info. What does your javascript look like?

Comment: Is `visible="false"` a special asp.net attribute thingy? What *exactly* does it do? You should certainly provide a better problem description than " it's not working".

Comment: what i am doing is initially div will not be visible ,if certain conditions occurred i am trying show that div content through jquery.

Comment: if (inStateCount > 0) {

                alert("inside if");
                $("#divFinaltargetGroup").css('visibility', 'visible')
                $("#divFinaltargetGroup").show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runat="server"` and `visible="false"` will cause the control/element to not even be rendered on the page. Use `style="display:none;"` instead of the `visible` attribute.

Also, since you're using `runat="server"`, asp.net will change the id on you. Try this for the selector:

```
$('#<%= divFinaltargetGroup.ClientID %>')
```

An alternative would be to give your element a class to select.

Comment: After doing it, the easiest way to toggle visibility (toggle, show, hide) of this div (which will be renamed in client side) is to add a class. Then you can use `$(".CLASS_NAME").show()`